# one key has multiple value, and need the max among the value with key

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary

mydict = {'Name1':['2', '3', '6'], 'Name2':['1', '6', '8', '10'], 'Name3':['6', '4', '10']}

I need code to get this:

mynewdict = {'Name1':['6'], 'Name2':['10'], 'Name3':['10']}

I tried:

> > > for key, value in mydict:
> > >
> > > ```
> > >  print (np.max(value))
> > > ```

ValueError: too many values to unpack

TIA

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in` only enumerates the `key`s:

```
for key in mydict:
    print(np.max(mydict[key]))
```

To enumerate with `key, value`, call `.iteritems()` first:

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    print(np.max(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  dict comprehension and use custom `sorted` to pick max value, since values are strings

```
In [4312]: {k: [sorted(v, key=lambda x: float(x))[-1]] for k, v in mydict.items()}
Out[4312]: {'Name1': ['6'], 'Name2': ['10'], 'Name3': ['10']}
```

Comment: I have a large dictionary, and this code may be good for smaller dict.
For my one, it gives an error.


ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.73398390565'

Comment: The value I want should be the max value in the list. 
I appreciate your code. It takes the last value.

Comment: @EmdadurRahman It takes the last value of the sorted list. You can just change int to float - next time, be clear about requirements in your question.